# my toolbar shows late after an empty space appears

Tags: android, toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

i have been using the support library to hide/show my toolbar but suddenly i had a strange error.

when i scoll up i get an empty space filling my toolbar's bounds and then after a couple of swipes i finally get the toolbar showing above this space.

after digging i found that the space is not anyview but the android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout (i tested by changing the background).

Now the problem appears to be that the RecyclerView decreases size before the toolbar take this size.

here is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.myapp.ListActivity"
    android:background="#F00F00" >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/myappbarlayout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/mytoolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/list_results"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/listselection"
            android:background="@color/primary_light"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/noitems"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
            android:text="No items "
            android:gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone"/>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?